# dispatch_async NSURLConnection - download don't start

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, dispatch

I'm trying to download information in background from a url.
I've read about GCD, Runloops and threads and decided that dispatc_async is my way to go.
After receiving data I aalso want to update the gui.
But... the NSUrlConnection don't seem to start at all. The delegate don't receive any calls.
I'v used this NSUrlRequest and NSUrlConnection in a synchronous way and the delegate got the data excpected.

Here is my code, a method in a viewcontroller;

```
- (void)dispatch: (NSURLRequest *) pRequest respondTo: (VivaQuery *) pQuery   {

    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue =          dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

        NSURLConnection *tConnectionResponse =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: pRequest delegate: pQuery];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             NSLog(@"Got to main thread.");
             [pQuery requestEnd]; // Will update gui, i e aUIView setNeedsDisplay 
         });
    });
}
```

Anyone got an idea?
Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Jan Gifvars
Stockholm

Answer (score 0):

NSUrlConnection does its work asynchronously on it's own background thread so you do not need to create it in a background thread.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thougt so too... but then I have somproblem updating the gui from that thread started by NSUrlConnection. I post another question on that issue. Thanks again.